# Unable to upload a video using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to upload a video file using `ajax`. But the following code doesn't work. When I click the upload button, I get a browser error saying :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

---

```
$('#uploadmatch').click(function(event) {
                                    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax( {
                    url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/UploadMatch',
                    data : formData,
                  //processData : false,
                    type : 'POST'
                })
                                    .done(function(message) {
                                        alert(message);
                                    })
                                    .fail(function(message){
                                        alert(message);
                                    })
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Trupti You think? Did you verify the value for attribute URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the data passed. I've tested your code and the formData object seems to be the problem. You are using it wrong. The FormData has an append which you have to use. I found a nice example on how you can upload files via AJAX (http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) and they are using FormData.

Here is the code example:

First you prepare the files

```
// Variable to store your files
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
  files = event.target.files;
}
```

Then the AJAX call:

```
  $('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

    // Create a formdata object and add the files
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php?files',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                // Success so call function to process the form
                submitForm(event, data);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle errors here
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
}
```